# Is a continuos and injective mapping from circle to a jordan curve is surjective ?  

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Is a continuos and injective mapping from circle to a jordan curve is surjective ?

Comment: That's a cool question for an exam in point set topology!

Comment: What percentage of answers in the class was right: 0-20? 21-40? 41-60? 61-80? 81-100? 101-120?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Let $f:S^{1}\rightarrow S^{1}$ be continuous and injective. Then by compactness of $S^{1}$, the image $f[S^{1}]$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. In particular, $f[S^{1}]$ is a compact connected subset of $S^{1}$, so $f[S^{1}]$ is either an interval or $S^{1}$ and $f[S^{1}]$ is not an interval since $f[S^{1}]$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. Therefore $f[S^{1}]=S^{1}$.